# Java: reading from named pipe written to by C via JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface, pipe, named-pipes

I'm attempting to communicate between a C program and a Java program.  The C program (in a separate thread) is run through JNI and writes to a named pipe we'll call `my_pipe`.  This works fine; I can verify that everything is getting written here by running `cat` in the terminal.

The problem comes, though, when I'm attempting to read the Strings written to the pipe.  I'm not sure what the correct object to use is.  I've looked around stackoverflow and tried fiddling around with Random Access Files and Scanners and such.  It seems I might have a blocking problem because I always get hung up on the read commands---such as RAF.readUTF8() and Scanner.hasNext().

STRUCTURE: Create a thread to run C program via JNI (all writing in this thread); Create a thread to read a File (the pipe) until the first thread is no longer alive (all reading in this thread).

Ultimately, I'm trying to redirect the C output to a JTextArea, so any solution making that easier is a plus.

Comment: Could you not just read in the bytes and then make the String? Or are you asking how to do that? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[]%29

Comment: Yeah, I'm having problem getting any data from the pipe.  I tried reading bytes, but I ran into the same problem that I talked about above.

Comment: `readUTF()` is only for data that has been written by `writeUTF()`.

Comment: @EJP Remember, I'm writing to the pipe with C code, so I would just need to encode using UTF8, not actually have to use that specific Java method, correct?  It shouldn't make a difference, right?